# Is there a way to automatically backup files everyday and highlight diffs everyday

Tags: linux, windows, git

Background: Sometime while editing my code, an important line had gotten deleted. I do not know how. In any case, I had a backup I had manually made of the code elsewhere with which I was able to do a diff and incorporate the missed line.

Is there a way/application to make the above process automatic daily either on windows or on linux?

That is, is there a way without manual intervention, to backup specific files (text-based code files) on a daily basis (ideally, this should be user specified) and each time the user wants to check the change from any of the previous versions (including, say, yesterday's), the change can be highlighted?

Can this be setup on `git`, say? From what I understand, even on `git`, this would be a manual process. Is there a way to automate this by writing a batch file or script, etc.? For some reason, `git` appears a bad idea for this since ideally, I would like to save on `git` only working code and not buggy code. I'd like to do this backup and daily diff on code that is in development and nowhere close to being in production.

Comment: " I would like to save on git only working code and not buggy code." this is a meaningless distinction.  You save changed code with `git`.  `git rebase` can rewrite history to clean up a branch before being merged.   If you want to be able to look through historical changes, you need to commit.  Get into the habit of committing code often while you work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.techjunkie.com/automatically-zip-files-batch-file/) link, I was able to create a batch file on windows that does this using 7zip. I have the following structure: `c:\myproject\` under which there is `\src\` and `\include\`. A date-stamped zip file, `src_date.zip` and `include_date.zip` get created on running the following batch file in `c:\myproject\zipdir\`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM ---- change according to your 7-zip path

set path="c:\Program Files\7-Zip";%path%

set "zipdirsrc=C:\myproject\src"

set "zipdirinc=C:\myproject\include"

set "movedir=C:\myproject\zipdir"

REM ---- end change accordingly

pushd %zipdirsrc%
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
ECHO Zipping all contents of %zipdirsrc% and moving archive src to %movedir%
7z a -tzip "%movedir%\src_%TODAY%.zip" -r "%zipdirsrc%\*.*" -mx5
ECHO SRC Task Complete ...

pushd %zipdirinc%
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
ECHO Zipping all contents of %zipdirinc% and moving archive include to %movedir%
7z a -tzip "%movedir%\include_%TODAY%.zip" -r "%zipdirinc%\*.*" -mx5
ECHO INCLUDE Task Complete ...
EXIT /B 0
```

It does not automatically highlight the diff (that is something I would have to do outside, I suppose), and I would have to run this manually, but before I embark on any major code change in development, this creates a zipped copy of the folders I need.